# How to extract embedded XML content from a plain text file?

Tags: java, xml

I have a huge text file and I wanted to write a program which can extract only the XMLs from the file and save it.

Is there a direct API or better solution than splitting/trimming the string read from the file.

Example:
small part of the file:

```
#---------- #1 :  ----------#
<MSG_INFO>
<message type="TextMessage" messageSelector="" originationTimestamp="" receiveTime="" jmsServerTimestamp="" jmsMsgExpiration="">
    <header JMSDestinationType="Generic" JMSDeliveryMode="2" />
    <properties>
        <property name="messageTopic" type="String">xyz</property>
    </properties>
</message>
```

```
 BodyLength=1476
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
<book id="bk101">
  <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
  <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
  <genre>Computer</genre>
  <price>44.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
  <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
  with XML.</description>
</book>
<book id="bk102">
  <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
  <title>Midnight Rain</title>
  <genre>Fantasy</genre>
  <price>5.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
  <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
  an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
  of the world.</description>
</book>
```

Comment: I don't understand.  Are you saying you have a text file with embedded XML 'snippets'?  Java has a variety of APIs available for parsing (well-formed) XML.

Comment: What @AndrewThompson said. What do you mean with "only the XMLs". Can you give a short example?

Comment: Is the user going to input an entire xml file in your input? Then CDATA it!

Comment: @Andrew I have updated the post with example. Please take a look. As you said I can parse xml from text file (containing both normal text and xml), could you please provide an example. Thanks

Comment: Can someone please answer this question? the text file I am receiving from the system it has both, simple text and xml. I just need to find the XML and extract it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expression was the answer.

```
String[] newXml = xml.split("\\<\\?");
    ArrayList<String> xmlList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(newXml));
    for(int i = 0; i<xmlList.size();i++){
        if(!xmlList.get(i).contains("xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"")){
            xmlList.remove(i);
        }

    }
    for(int j = 0;j<xmlList.size();j++){
        xmlList.set(j, "<?"+xmlList.get(j));
        xmlList.set(j,xmlList.get(j).split("\\#")[0]);
    }


    return xmlList;
```

Comment: By the way, this gives only the first XML in the document. But we can always use recursive technique to get all of them.

Comment: this is a non hungry pattern to extract the first xml in what if file contains raw text before and after the xml. ? will doesn't help over there do you have a workaround of that.

Answer (score 1):

Generally an XML file is a text file, so either you have one file that is XML, or you have a file that contains multiple fragments of XML.

If the former, you need to learn about XML processing (SAX, DOM, etc.) to get to the structured contents of the XML document, then you can save that content with it's structure.  This is useful when wanting to reformat an XML document (tabbing in nested tags or putting everything on one line are examples).

If the latter, you need to write a parser and then use the XML processing tools.  The first parser will look for anything that appears to be an open-XML tag, and then keep track of the tag's position in the text file, counting subsequent open and close tags until it detects it left the top-level nesting of the initial tag.  Then it needs to pass the embedded chunk of text (without passing in the rest of the document) to the appropriate XML parsing facility, which might then form a representational view of the XML, which might then be reprocessed back to text for saving in it's own file.

Of course, the latter can be optimized to not actually parse the XML after it's beginning and ending boundary has been detected; however, without actually parsing the XML, there will be no guarantee that the resulting chunk of text is actually valid XML.

Answer (score 0):

Consider taking a look at these for Java XML Parsing:

- [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/)
- [XOM](http://xom.nu/)
- [Woodstox](http://woodstox.codehaus.org/)

Comment: Can any of these extract the xml from a text file (containing both XMLs and normal text)? Thanks